# Is akavache thread safe on iOS?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, akavache

I am using akavache component for caching on xamarin forms project.

The app works fine on android but crashes in unexpected moments on iOS. This could be to accessing the sql resource by multiple threads.

Akavache uses sql lite raw and this needs to be opened in full mutex flag for thread safety on iOS. As far as i observed this component does not have this flag set on iOs when creating SQLiteConnection. Do i need any special setting in order to use akavache? Does anybody have expirence with this component on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question](https://github.com/reactiveui/Akavache/issues/335) Akavache on iOS is thread safe since version 5.